# Local copy ahead of master

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-clone, git-pull

I recently made a mess of one of my projects that I track with Git. I made several changes, and instead of reverting the changes of my local repo back, I decided to clone the repo again into another directory on my machine, to create a backup of sorts (kind of redundant, I know). I then went ahead and *did* revert the changes in my original local repo, and did not use/do not need the new clone, since I was able to fix everything in the original local copy.

The issue is now when I try to push to GitHub, Git throws the following error:

```
To github.com:<my-username>/<repo-name>.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:<my-username>/<repon-ame>.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I haven't pushed anything to the repo since cloning it, and no one else is working on the project, so I'm unsure why it would be ahead of my local copy. Does simply cloning it to another directory result in the master being ahead?

So my question is, how I can go ahead and push this without first pulling in from master, as I'm sure the `git pull` is just going to erase the changes I've made to my local file, in the original directory (first clone). I'll manually copy/paste to update the files if I have to, as there aren't many, and I won't be returning to this project afterwards. But I'm just looking for some clarification, and the safest way I can update the repo, even if that is copy and paste, though I imagine there is a better way.

I'm still getting the hang of Git, so any guidance is appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you push your mess to the remote repo before you fixed it? Or is it just on your local machine?

Comment: Did you use git reset for reverting in the original repo?

Comment: Thanks @Ali I did not push the mess. My remote repo has not been changed in a few days, but my local copy (from the first clone) has all the bug fixes that I did today. Now I wan to push those bug fixes to the remote, but am getting the error above

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Mudassarhassan. I did not. I use VS Code, and reverted my mess back to match the remote from VS Code in the "Source Control" tab. This resulted in my current code (from the first clone) to match the remote exactly. Then I made a bunch of bug fixes locally, and tried to push, and am now getting that error. So in reality, my local is ahead of the remote, but Git thinks otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
git fetch origin master
```

This command will update your local copy of the remote repo without touching your local repo or working directory. This way you can see what the difference is between the remote branch and your local branch by running the following command:

```sh
git diff origin/master
```

You can then run one of the following as appropriate:

```sh
# Run this to keep any changes from the remote branch
git rebase origin/master
git push origin master

# Run this to overwrite changes on the remote branch
git push --force origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to push with -f flag `git push origin master -f`

Answer (score 0):

Try this git command

```
git push origin master --force
```

or short of force -f

```
git push origin master -f
```